# C function that prints the number n in the exponent form of k, for 2<=k<=16. E.G. for n=200 and k=8, the print is "200=3*8**2+1*8**1"

Tags: c, function, math

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void foo (int n, int k){
    int rez=1;
    int trenutnirez;
    int highest_exp=0;
    if (k<2 || k>16){
        printf ("INCORRECT");
        return NULL;
    }
    while (rez<n){
        rez*=k;
        highest_exp++;
    }
    rez=n;
    highest_exp--;


}
int main (){
    foo(200,8);
    return 0;
}
```

I get to here and calculate the highest exponent, dunno where to next?
this is my collage lab, don't usually ask here so feel free to be as slow as possible with me.

Comment: Well, maybe OT but you can't return NULL from function with `void` return type.

Comment: Thats not the issue, and it works this way, but I can always comment it out, Thanks for the comment :)

Comment: Yes, it wouldn't solve the issue, hence the OT (off-topic) reference, but you shouldn't do it anyway, so yes, commenting it is the way to go ;)

Comment: The only thing your code prints is `NEVALJA` whatever that means. So please clarify. What is the program supposed to do?

Comment: its in the title

Comment: It's very unclear but I suppose `rez=n;` doesn't make any sense. Your code calculates the result in `rez`, but in the end you overwrite `rez` with `n`.

Comment: Please modify your code so it prints the result, and show some examples of input and expected vs. actual output.

Comment: After what you have currently done, you must find the coefficients to apply to each power of k starting with hightest_exp . Factor[highest_exp] = rez / power(k, highest_exp), then do the same with the remainder and highest_exp - 1. This can be done with recursion, functions, loops. It is up to you to define the design.

Answer (score 0):

What you're tasked with is number conversion from base 10 to other bases (namely base 2 to base 16).

Essentially,

```
n = coef(xp) * b^(xp) + coef(xp-1) * b^(xp-1) + ... + coef(1) * b^(0) + coef(0) * b^(0)
```

where the following are non-negative integers:

- `n` is the given number,
- `coef(t)` represents the coefficient with index *t*,
- `b` is the base to which you're converting, and
- `xp` is the highest exponent.

The way this is done is by repeated division and remainder operations. In pseudo code:

```
for i = xp to 0 inclusive:
    coef = n / b**i        // '/' is integer division, '**' is exponentiation
    n = n % b**i           // '%' is the remainder operation

    if coef > 0:
        if i != xp:
            print " + "
        endif
        print coef, " * ", b, "**", i
    endif
endfor
```

From this a fairly straightforward implementation can be done in C. Note that you might want to *cache* the value of `b**i` so that it isn't calculated multiple times, and that you need a function to perform the calculation in the first place (I recommend you write one yourself) since C doesn't offer an exponentiation operator, except for binary numbers.

---

A couple of comments on the code you've written so far:

- one of the standard-prescribed definitions of the `main` function *when it doesn't take any arguments* is `int main(void) { ... }` – don't deviate from that, unless you're trying to invoke some implementation-defined behavior for your particular implementation;
- returning `NULL` from a function whose return type is `void` is undefined behavior (from 6.8.6.4, C99 standard):

  > A `return` statement with an expression shall not appear in a function whose return type is `void`.

  - what you instead want here is to `return EXIT_FAILURE;` (and change the type of value your function returns) and handle that in the calling function, or call `exit(EXIT_FAILURE);`, which causes normal process termination, with `EXIT_FAILURE` and `exit` being declared in `stdlib.h`; alternatively, a simple expressionless `return;` will do.

A couple of other observations:

- `trenutnirez` is uninitialized and unused;
- normally you want to append a newline when you're writing to standard output, which means appending `\n` to your `printf`'s format string, or simply using `puts`, which will do that automatically for you;
- consider declaring all your function prototypes at the top: this is useful because when you have multiple functions, you don't have to worry about which function comes first in order for all of them to be "visible" in all your functions (e.g., if you now add the exponentiation function below `foo`, which by the way you should rename to something more appropriate, it won't know the new function's signature).